# I can't access to mySQL with node js anymore

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, econnrefused

I have updated my node version, and now I can't access to my DB with my app. I tried many things:
-Change rout to 127.0.0.1.
-add my port number 3306
-add socketPath: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
-kill node running
And probably others, but I always have an error. Actually, I have this one while running this code.
Error:

```
disconnected
error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
```

My code who was working before:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "discord"
});
if (db.state === 'disconnected') {
    db.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) { return console.error('error: ' + err.message); }
        console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
    });
}
console.log(db.state);
module.exports = db
```

Comment: Is MySQL running? Also, check what's running on port 3306, if at all.

Comment: Yes it's running, do you have a command to check if something is on port 3306 ? I killed everything so it should be good

Comment: I tried this
`netstat -anpe | grep "3306" | grep "LISTEN"
netstat: e: unknown or uninstrumented protocol`

Comment: mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
 SUCCESS!

Comment: Maybe it's because of the connector C# ?
Name: root
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3306
Server: Homebrew
Version: 8.0.28
Connector: C++ 8.0.17

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the version of `discord.js` because I have updated it as well. I've changed it in my package.json for the one I used before and everything is working well. It will be hard to update all my app to the new version. If you have any recommendation to update it easily without running into multiple issues, I'm here !